# Switch between deep and shallow press Watch Simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, watchkit, xcode7, apple-watch

I'm in trouble because in Xcode 7 Apple as introduce the ability to switch between deep and shallow press on the Apple Watch Simulator but the shortcut is also use to change the scale. I was wondering if someone know how to change shortcuts or have another solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following shortcuts.

- Shallow Press: Shift + cmd + 1
- Deep Press: Shift + cmd + 2

[image]

The shortcuts to change scale is the following.

- cmd + 1
- cmd + 2

Comment: Yes I know that but in my case this shortcut is not working, I don't know why but it only change the scale like if the shift key wasn't pressed